# FreeBSD: "Too many open files" but should be able to open another 160,000 files

Tags: freebsd, mysql

I have a FreeBSD 8 system running ZFS, with a MySQL 5.5 server which is about 355GB and projected to grow to be a couple of Terabytes.

MySQL is triggering errors about "Too many open files" on `/etc/hosts.allow`. We don't expressly use `/etc/hosts.allow`, but it is used by [hosts_access(3)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hosts_access&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) (`libwrap.a`), which is used by many things.

```
mysqld[1234]: warning: /etc/hosts.allow, line 15: cannot open /etc/hosts.allow: Too many open files
```

But when I check 't seem to be hitting any actual limits. The number of open files reported by `kern.openfiles stays` below 40,000 over a sustained period, and our limit is substantially higher:

```
# sysctl -a |grep files
kern.maxfiles: 204800
kern.maxfilesperproc: 184320
kern.openfiles: 38191

# ulimit -n
184320
```

Openfiles should be set to unlimited:

```
# grep openfiles /etc/login.conf
    :openfiles=unlimited:\
```

MySQL says it should be able to open 184320 file handles:

```
# mysqladmin variables | grep open_files_limit
| open_files_limit                              |     184320                |
```

And some information from the perspective of the MySQL user. I stopped mysql and hacked `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server` to print out these variables, so this should represent the MySQL environment. Note that the number 184320 is consistent with the above.

```
# /usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server.stefantest start
Starting mysql.
cpu time               (seconds, -t)  unlimited
file size           (512-blocks, -f)  unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d)  33554432
stack size              (kbytes, -s)  524288
core file size      (512-blocks, -c)  unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m)  unlimited
locked memory           (kbytes, -l)  unlimited
max user processes              (-u)  5547
open files                      (-n)  184320
virtual mem size        (kbytes, -v)  unlimited
swap limit              (kbytes, -w)  unlimited
sbsize                   (bytes, -b)  unlimited
pseudo-terminals                (-p)  unlimited
```

And, for easy reference here are the descriptions for the sysctls:

```
kern.maxfiles: Maximum number of files
kern.openfiles: System-wide number of open files
kern.maxfilesperproc: Maximum files allowed open per process
```

**Related**

- This is possibly related to a ZFS on Nexenta question on ServerFault:
  [Why is MySQL unable to open hosts.allow/hosts.deny?](https://serverfault.com/questions/457216/why-is-mysql-unable-to-open-hosts-allow-hosts-deny#comment539779_457216)
- Also see this similar issue on the FreeBSD forums: [[EMFILE] Too many
  open files](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=37547)

Comment: ulimit isn't global, are you sure that's the same ulimit your MySQL is running with?

Comment: Right, but isn't `kern.maxfilesperproc` global? I updated my question with some info from MySQL's perspective.

Comment: @StefanLasiewski: indeed it is, but `ulimit` is set per shell. And this can decrease the system-imposed limit further!

Comment: I see. I assumed that if `ulimit` is unset, then `ulimit` would inherit the value from `kernel.maxfilesperproc`. See http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=1553 . But in my case, maybe it is set somewhere-- just can't find out where.

Comment: So, can I see what the ulimit value is for the MySQL daemon, and can I change the ulimit value for the daemon without stopping the daemon? I know I can set `ulimit` in the startup script or the shell environment, but that would require that I interrupt the database.

Comment: Look in /proc, under the subdir with the PID of your mysql service.  You can `cat limits` to see what mysql is running with. You can also change them on the fly (with newer kernels): `echo -n "Max open files=soft_value:hard_value" > /proc/$PID/limits` (as root of course)

Comment: @lornix: this is FreeBSD. I've never used BSD myself, but I'm not sure if FreeBSD actually supports /proc/*/limits.

Comment: `# ls -l /proc/*
ls: No match.`

Comment: `/proc` isn't mounted by default on FreeBSD, but do it yourself with `sudo mount -t procfs proc /proc`, see `procfs(5)` for more info.  Once you have `/proc` mounted, look at `/proc/$PID/rlimit` file

Comment: As far as I recall ZFS is a HUGE user of vnodes. What is a `kern.maxvnodes` setting on your server? Can you set it higher to at least two to four times `kern.maxfiles`?

Answer (score 1):

Check /etc/login.conf and figure out which login class your mysql user assigned to.  It's probably default or daemon.  If you want to alter the limits for your user, create a new class, assign your user to that class, change the limts for that class as you like and then run "cap_mkdb /etc/login.conf"

If you haven't read this yet, do: http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/users-limiting.htm

Processes started at system startup by /etc/rc are assigned to the *daemon* login class.

Answer (score 0):

On some OS the limits are set to avoid security problem to regular user, you should consider reading whant in the `man limits.conf`
This file defines the limits per process like max number of thread or max number of open file.
The limitation use face could come from there.
`/etc/security/limits.conf`