# "Too many open files ssh" when the number of open files is far below ulimit

Tags: ssh, sshd, open-files, ulimit

I was trying to set up 2000 concurrent ssh connections, but got the error message in server log (i.e. `journalctl`):

```
sshd[1356]: error: reexec socketpair: Too many open files
```

I've set both the soft and hard limit for `nofile` in `/etc/security/limits.conf`, and `ulimit -n` gives me 1 048 000.

Also, `Max open files` in `/proc/<ssh_pid>/limits`is 1 048 000, which is consistent with the value of `nofile` mentioned above (i.e. the value for `ulimit`).

When my script for setting up ssh connections was running, I tried `lsof | wc -l` several times and the values it gave me were around 260 000, which is much less than the open file limit.

So my question is why it complains about "Too many open files" when the actual number of open files is far below the limit?

This question seems similar but I still don't know what to do after reading it:
[FreeBSD: "Too many open files" but should be able to open another 160,000 files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66863/freebsd-too-many-open-files-but-should-be-able-to-open-another-160-000-files)

Any idea is appreciated!

Comment: Do a quick sanity check of the limit being used by sshd.  cat /proc/<pid>/limits

Comment: @steve thanks for the comment, but I think I have mentioned in the main post that I have checked the `/proc/<ssh_pid>/limits` already and that the `Max open files` is 1 048 000?

Comment: Did you change the limits for all users or just root? sshd will fork a process and change user to the one connecting to it. Note that in `man socketpair` you have both `EMFILE` and `ENFILE`, the latter refers to the `systemy-wide` limits on the number of open file descriptors. What does `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` say ?